# Is it possible to resize the cropped image before uploading it with CropperJs?

Tags: cropperjs

I can't see anything about resizing [in the docs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs), although they have [an example of "maximum cropped dimensions"](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/examples/minimum-and-maximum-cropped-dimensions.html).

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
When getting the cropped canvas, you can specify your desired size and then send to server or do whatever

[getCroppedCanvas](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md#getcroppedcanvasoptions) is the method you may want to use with specifying width & height of your resize